# Google Glass compile error on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to create a google glass app(immersion based) on Android Studio 1.1.0 and this error throws up.

**Error:Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Sampleapp\app\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19.jar'.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**

I previously tried on eclipse and it all worked fine but in Android Studio it's a little weird.

**Update**

Project: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'prebuilt-libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.Sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: This seems to be only a problem since Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: @MariusHerzog  Yes. Changing the classpath to 1.1.+ or 1.0.0 fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a classpath of `1.1.+` instead. Either way, it probably has something to do with the inability of Gradle to escape the dot after `Google Inc.` in the path.

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

This error appears if you use

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
```

The highest level of Gradle build tools supported for Glass development is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Yes i am using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0' .                          I changed it to 1.0.1 manually and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Vinay 1.0.0 works for me try that EDIT: So does 1.0.1 so you might have an aditional problem somewhere. I've had the same error before as you but changing to 1.0.0 or 1.0.1 always fixed it for me